# how to handle file upload window in RIDE robot framework

Tags: robotframework

In my application, on clicking `Select File`, it opens a local browser wherein I need to select the file `BOX1` to upload it in my application. How can i implement this scenario in RIDE (robot framework)?

I had tried the below keyword "Choose File"

```
Choose file   xpath of the Select File button    filepath of BOX1 file
```

Its throwing an error. This is not working.

[image]

Comment: Not related to RIDE (Robot Framework IDE)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the operating system file browser, you should not click the "Select File" button. Change your code so that the locator for `Choose File` is the element `<input>` with the `type="file"`.